# 500 internal server error for the API handling image using s3 in spring boot (works on localhost)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, amazon-s3, http-status-code-500

```
@PostMapping(value = "/driver", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<?> saveDriver(@Valid @ModelAttribute DriverRequest driverRequest) throws IOException, ImageResolutionExceededException {
        LocalTime time = LocalTime.now();
        DriverResponse driverResponse = driverService.saveDriver(driverRequest, time);
        driverService.saveFiles(driverRequest.profileImage(),
                driverRequest.drivingLicenseImage(),
                driverRequest.rcBookImage(),
                time);

        return ResponseEntity
                .status(HttpStatus.CREATED)
                .body(new BaseResponse(HttpStatus.CREATED.value(),
                        messageSource.getMessage(
                                "api.successfully.saved.response",
                                new String[] {Constant.DRIVER},
                                Locale.getDefault()),
                        driverResponse));
    }
```

`DriverRequest` include String fullName, MultipartFile profileImage, String mobileNumber and other similar fields.

When I hit this API from localhost it successfully create driver entry in `driver` table and also save the profileImage, drivingLicenseImage, rcBookImage on `s3`. But when I use same API on server it is giving `500 internal server error.`

If anyone has face same issue, please share your solution. Thank you in advance :)

Comment: I think you need to look at server logs for details on the 500